# Prove that $AY$ is perpendicular to $BP$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, triangles, pythagorean-triples

> $ABC$ is a rt. angled triangle rt. angled at $A$. $ACPQ, BCYX, ABSR$ are squares drawn on $AC, BC , AB$ respectively. Prove that $AY$ is perpendicular to $BP$.

[image]

I couldnt proceed beyond congruency of the triangles $CPB$ and $CAY$. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After using rotation of $\Delta BCP$ on $90^{\circ}$ around the point $C$ we'll get $\Delta YCA$ we'll get 
$BP=AY$ and even $BP\perp AY$.

Comment: Yep! Got it, thanks!

Comment: @Amitayas Banerjee You are welcome!